Problem with catching data from Oracle XE 21c over db link from database MySql 8.0.32
We have problem when we want catch data from Oracle XE 21c over db link from database MySql 8.0.32, when we use where condition on select the results are waiting for a very long time.
For example :
MySQL
select * FROM MO_V_PARTNERI;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 18.759  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 13,781 sec. */
select * FROM MO_V_PARTNERI where sif_par = '059666436';
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0,015 sec. */
Oracle
select * from mo_v_partneri@DB_LINK_TEST;     30,762 sec.
select * from mo_v_partneri@DB_LINK_TEST where sif_par = '059666436'; - this one is never executed
Does anyone have any solution ?

The issue you are experiencing with the slow performance of the SELECT queries when using a database link from MySQL to Oracle XE 21c is likely due to a combination of factors, including network latency, database configuration, and query optimization. Here are some potential solutions to address the problem:
Check the Database Link Configuration

Ensure that the database link is configured correctly, with the appropriate connection details and credentials.
Verify that the database link is not experiencing any network-related issues, such as high latency or packet loss.
Consider using a dedicated network connection or a faster network protocol (e.g., TCP/IP) to improve the performance of the database link.

Optimize the Queries

Analyze the execution plans for the slow-running queries to identify any potential bottlenecks, such as missing indexes or suboptimal join conditions.
Ensure that the sif_par column in the MO_V_PARTNERI table is indexed, as this will significantly improve the performance of the query with the WHERE clause.
Consider adding appropriate indexes to the tables involved in the database link queries to speed up the data retrieval process.

Adjust Database Configuration Parameters

On the Oracle XE 21c side, review the SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT and SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT parameters in the sqlnet.ora file, and adjust them if necessary to prevent connection timeouts.
On the MySQL side, ensure that the connection pool settings are configured correctly to handle the database link connections efficiently.

Use Caching Mechanisms

If the data in the MO_V_PARTNERI table is relatively static, consider implementing a caching mechanism in your application to reduce the number of queries executed against the database link.
This could involve storing the data in an in-memory cache (e.g., Redis, Memcached) or using a caching layer in your application.

Partition the Data

If the MO_V_PARTNERI table contains a large amount of data, consider partitioning the table based on the sif_par column or another suitable column. Partitioning the data can significantly improve the performance of queries that filter on the partitioned column, as the database can quickly identify and access the relevant partitions.

Investigate Potential Deadlocks or Locking Issues

Check for any potential deadlocks or locking issues that may be causing the queries to wait for a long time.
Review the database logs and monitor the database activity to identify any potential concurrency-related problems. By addressing these potential issues, you should be able to improve the performance of the queries executed through the database link from MySQL to Oracle XE 21c

